# Residual Mod 3 Representation Attached to Elliptic Curve is Not Induced By a Certain Galois Group

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

In Cornell, Silverman, Stevens, "Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem," Edixhoven, the author of  the chapter on Serre's Conjecture, asserts a few times, beginning on page 234 of the text, that if $E/\mathbb Q$ is an elliptic curve such that the residual mod $3$ representation

$$\rho_3: G_{\mathbb Q} \to \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_3)$$

attached to $E$ is irreducible, where $G_{\mathbb Q}$ is the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb Q$, then this representation is not induced by $G(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3}))$. I cannot for the life of me find where the text has proven or given reference for anything resembling this result. What we do know is that this representation is absolutely irreducible.

Can someone provide me with either a reference for this fact or a proof?

Comment: This is Proposition 2.1 of the same article. Of course, you need $E$ to not be CM and to be semistable. A key observation is that $\rho_3$ is induced from that extension if and only if $\rho_3\otimes\chi_3 \simeq\rho_3$, where $\chi_3$ is the mod $3$ cyclotomic character.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide more details? Why do we need E to not have CM? Why are we allowed to take E without CM since Proposition 2.1 does not specify that and since Modularity is supposed to work for any semistable elliptic curve? Why is your key observation true? Why does this statement follow from Proposition 2.1?

Comment: For example, if $E\colon y^2 = x^3 + 1$, then the $3$-adic Galois representation is induced from $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3})$. On the other hand, for CM curves, modularity was already proven by Taniyama and Shimura! (I think it was them. It was certainly well known before Wiles). Oh also... CM curves over $\mathbb Q$ are not semistable.

Comment: The key observation is a fun exercise with Frobenius reciprocity. The statement follows from Prop 2.1 as induced representations cannot be surjective (they have a reducible index 2 subgroup)

Comment: Wonderful! Sorry, to clarify: where in the proof are we using that E does not have CM?

Comment: Where in which proof? As a general rule, if an elliptic curve has CM defined over $K$, then its $G_K$ Galois representation is reducible. So a CM elliptic curve has Galois representations that become reducible over quadratic extensions. The flip side is that the reducibility means that the question of modularity reduces to the modularity of one-dimensional Galois representations - i.e. class field theory.

Comment: I see; I think this is then subsumed under the semistable assumption. One last thing I do not understand is why an induced representation cannot be surjective. Is this a general fact from representation theory?

Comment: Yes. The image is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_3)$ that contains an index $2$ reducible (so cyclic) subgroup. Essentially, the image looks like a dihedral group.

Comment: Where can I learn more generally about this type of theory?

Comment: For the basic rep theory, I'm not sure. But for its applications to elliptic curves, Serre's green book (Abelian l-Adic Representations and Elliptic Curves) is a great place to start

Comment: I thought I understood this, but now I don't see why the index 2 subgroup of the image must be cyclic. I could see why this would be true if $G(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3}))$ was cyclic, but I do not see why this should be the case.

Comment: Sorry - not cyclic, but abelian. The restriction is a direct sum of two one-dimensional representations.

Comment: And how do we know that?

Comment: That's just Frobenius reciprocity/Mackey theory. $\rho = \mathrm{ind}(\chi)$ for some $\chi$, so $\rho|_K = \chi + \chi^c$, where $c$ is the non-trivial element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q)$ and $\chi^c(g):= \chi(cgc^{-1})$.